# Try/except - how to continue

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

So there is a part in my program where I ask the user to enter a number. I use try/exept as:

```
limits=True
while limits:
        try:
            limits=int(input("Put your limit:"))
            return limits
        except(ValueError):
            print("Thats not a number!")
```

My question is if the user does put in a number how can I continue to use the variable `limits` that contains the users input later on in my code?

After that the try/except part runs and when the user to put in a number it just stops, doesn't continue with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is this I don't even.

You're trying to make limits both a boolean for the while loop, and an integer for something else.

Try one of these methods:

- make a while loop that checks the validity of the input, rather than
  try to read it as a boolean
- make a while true loop, which will already break on the return statement if the input is correct.

tl;dr replace **while limits** with **while true**.

Comment: Wait, you're not making a method that returns limits are you... 

If you have more code underneath this code that you want to run afterwards, don't return limits. Just break.

Comment: If you don't know what break is, well, just type break.

Comment: yes I am making a method that returns limt should I just put break where I did put return?

Comment: If you're just trying to have the method return the number the user inputs after making sure it's a number, all you need to do is replace While(limits) with while(true) and it'll work. If you want more code underneath the while loop to run, then replace return limits with break as well.

Comment: Never mind I got it, where you put while(true) it should of course be while(True) with a capital T

Comment: Am I just exiting the loop while the user has entered a valid number right?

Comment: Breaks exit loops when they're executed. A while true loop should run forever, unless you use a break, which breaks the loop and continues on running the code after the loop, or return, which only works when you're in some kind of method and means you've gotten what you called the method for, and that code doesn't need to run anymore. It then returns that value and goes back to wherever the method was called from.

Comment: Is that why my code stoped when i tried to put the code above under a method like and when i put return it didnt to anything after that?

Comment: Yep. That or it was running the loop indefinitely, because your integer would be evaluated as true, because it's not 0. The reason for that is sort of complicated. You'll get to it eventually, for the time being, just make sure you use something that's either true or false in your if statements and while loops and such.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need `limits` at all in your code:

```
def get_limit():
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input("Enter your limit: "))
        except(ValueError):
            print("That's not a number!")
```

To use the value later in your code, just assign the return value from the function to some variable:

```
limit = get_limit()
```

Comment: I now tried your advice and have def get_limit(self): 
then the code you wrote 
then i put limit=get_limit and I want to use it in an if -statement under the get_limit method. It doesnt seem to work tough

Comment: Technically, that while(limits) he had wasn't doing anything. The only time that loop would break is if it got set to 0. Sometimes I forget how cool python is.